# Is there any reason why Aizawa and Shinso use the same cloth-type capturing weapon?

Tags: my-hero-academia

In **Chapter 197** of the manga, Hitoshi Shinso use the same cloth-type capturing weapon that Shota Aizawa uses. Is there any reason why Aizawa and Shinso use the same type of capturing weapon? Were these given to Shinso by Aizawa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Is there any reason why Shota Aizawa and Hitoshi Shinso use the same clothes?** Heroes have the option to use support items. [Since he was trained by Aizawa](https://bokunoheroacademia.fandom.com/wiki/Hitoshi_Shinso), he was taught of the same techniques Aizawa used for Binding Cloth. Remember that Shinso's quirk is easily countered by his opponent not answering him so using a Binding Cloth would supplement for his lack of a counter-attack if ever this happens. It's the only ability he has that's close to an offensive-type and that can directly harm his opponents.

Same is true for Aizawa. Without the cloth, sure he can cancel out quirks but the opponent can still move. Hence, both use the same cloth to aid them in situations where their quirks (Brainwashing and Erasure) would be useless.

**Were these clothes given to Hitoshi Shinso by Shota Aizawa?** I'm not sure if it was ever mentioned directly that it was given to him but Shinso was trained by Aizawa, as briefly seen from a flashback in **Chapter 214**. It's possible it was and also, that he was taught by Aizawa how since he was able to use it, as seen in **Chapter 197**.

Comment: Did Aizawa personally trained or what and why? Is that seen in the manga?

Comment: @Pablo Yes, he personally trained him. A brief flashback is shown in Chapter 214.